# How do i launch app directly on a certain screen when app has only MainActivity?

Tags: testing, mobile, appium

The app has a welcome screen, with 2 buttons- signup and signin and also there's only one activity for the whole app- the MainActivity. So how do i launch app directly on, for example, sign in screen without loading welcome screen and then clicking on 'sign in' button?

If i understand it correctly, I could get there by specifying LoginActivity in desired capabilities, if there would be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible only if the app have the ability to do deep linking.